# WELD Exception when using SLSB interface

Tags: jboss7.x, cdi, jboss-weld

I have a Java EE 6 CDI based application running on JBoss AS 7.1.1 which contains some Session Beans too.

```
@Stateless
public class OrderService   {
@Inject
private Logger log;

@Inject
private EntityManager em;

    . . . . .
```

}

Everything worked fine until I had to expose my SLSB as a SOAP Web Service. So I had to provide an interface and declare the Web service:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(OrderServiceItf.class)
@WebService
public class OrderService implements OrderServiceItf  {

@Inject
private Logger log;

@Inject
private EntityManager em;

    . . . . .
}

@WebService
public interface OrderServiceItf  {
. . . .
}
```

Unfortunately once I deploy the application I get the following WELD exception whereever I use this Bean:
**org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [OrderService] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject com.telco.service.SendMessageService.orderService]**

```
public class SendMessageService implements Serializable {
@Inject
private Logger logger;

int money;
@Inject OrderService orderService;

}
```

Any help how can I sort out this issue ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just checked injecting **EJB** instead of **Inject** into my SendMessageService and it seems to work. (Hope I haven't broken the rest of the application.). Are there other options available out there ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Typed(OrderService)` and you should be good. This changes the metadata for that bean and instead of being of the interface type, CDI will recognize your EJB as the concrete type.